# Javascript/HTML error “the value of the property “selectReason” is null or undefined, not a function object

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to javascript and html and was wondering if someone could help me understand why this error keeps occuring. The basic idea is that i have a dropdownlist that is populated with several options. When the customer selects an option an onchange event fires that will write the value of the selected option into a textarea.  However when i debug it I get the message above I have included the relevant snippets of code below:

```
function selectReason() {
    var selectindex = document.getElementById("selectmessage").selectedIndex;    
    var selecttext = document.getElementById("selectmessage").value;
    document.getElementById("Txt").value = selecttxt;
}

<TR style="DISPLAY: none; VISIBILITY: hidden" id=sel>
    <TD width="60%" align=left>Please select a reason</TD>
    <TD width="40%" align=left>
        <SELECT id="selectmessage" onchange="selectReason()" style="WIDTH: 425px"></SELECT>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: you are missing `<script>` tag , i guess

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing your `<table>` tags as that was causing a problem for me. Your provided snippet also has `var selecttext` and `document.getElementById("Txt").value = selecttxt;` <- missing an e.

The provided snippet below works for me. Possibly just failing to close a tag somewhere in your function/html.

Also (this could be you added inline to provide a better picture) you should avoid inline styles and (to me) functions. Include a .css and .js file.

```js
function selectReason() {
  var selectindex = document.getElementById("selectmessage").selectedIndex;   
  var selecttext = document.getElementById("selectmessage").value;
  var elem = document.getElementById("hey");
  elem.innerHTML = selecttext;
}

// Events to attach
function init () {
  var elem = document.getElementById('selectmessage');
  elem.addEventListener('change', selectReason)
 }

// Run 'init' when the DOM is ready (jQuery's $(document).ready() )
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<table>
<TR>
<TD>Please select a reason</TD>
<TD>
  <SELECT id="selectmessage">
  <option>Hello</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
  </SELECT>
</TD>
</TR>
<tr>
    <td id='hey'></td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="" id="selectmessage">
                        <option value="red">red</option>
                        <option value="gree">green</option>
                        <option value="blue">blue</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <textarea name="" id="txt" cols="30" rows="10">


    </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready', function(){
            $('#selectmessage').on('change', function(){
                var val = $(this).val();

                var txt = $('#txt');

                    txt.val(val);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

hope :)